# Python for loop json.loads error string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I'm have been struggling with understanding the reason for the following Json parsing issue, I have tried many combinations to access the 'val' item value but I have hit a brick wall.

I have used the code below successfully on 'similar' Json style data, but I dont have the knowledge to craft this approach to the data below.

All advice gratefully accepted.

```
result = xmltodict.parse(my_read)
result = result['REPORT']['REPORT_BODY']
result =json.dumps(result, indent=1)

    print(result)

    {
 "PAGE": [
     {
      "D-ROW": [
       {
        "@num": "1",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
       },
       {
        "@num": "2",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "D-ROW": [
       {
        "@num": "26",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
       },
       {
        "@num": "27",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
       },
       {
        "@num": "28",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}

for item in json.loads(json_data):
    print(item['PAGE']['D-ROW']['val']
```

error string indices must be integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item['PAGE']` contains a list, so you cannot index it with `'D-ROW'`. If your json-loaded data is in a variable `data` you could use:

```
for page in data['PAGE']:
    for drow in page['D-ROW']:
        print drow['val']
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing should notice, based on your JSON structure is that it's a dict `{"PAGE": [...], ...}`, so when you use `json.loads()` on it, you'll get a dict too

In this `for` loop, your `item` iterator actually refers to the **key** from the dict

```
for item in json.loads(json_data):
    print(item['PAGE']['D-ROW']['val']
```

Here's a simpler example easier to follow

```
>>> for key in json.loads('{"a": "a-value", "b": "b-value"}'):
...     print(key)
...
a
b
```

> error string indices must be integers

So you can guess that in your loop `item` would refer to the key `"PAGE"`, and you can't index that string with `['D-ROW']` (`"PAGE"['D-ROW']` doesn't make sense, hence your error)

### Key/values in the for loop

To get items if you use the loop below, `item` becomes a tuple of `(key, value)`

```
for item in json.loads(json_data).items():
        print(item)
```

You can also expand the key, value like this

```
>>> for key, value in json.loads('{"a": "a-value", "b": "b-value"}').items():
...     print("key is {} value is {}".format(key, value))
...
key is a value is a-value
key is b value is b-value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON should not include quotes around values with numbers. For example, change

```
"D-ROW": [
   {
    "@num": "1",
    "type": "wew",
    "val": ".000"
   },
```

to

```
"D-ROW": [
   {
    "@num": 1, // Key requires quotes, Value omits quotes if number
    "type": "wew",
    "val": 0.000
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"D-ROW": [
       {
        "@num": "26",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
       },
       {
        "@num": "27",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
       },
       {
        "@num": "28",
        "type": "wew",
        "val": ".000"
    }
```

D-ROW key contains a list, not a dict.

You should change

```
print(item['PAGE']['D-ROW']['val']
```

to

```
print([_item['val'] for _item in item['PAGE']['D-ROW']])
```

to iterate over the list which contains you dicts.